# Spring hibernate ignore json object

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to remove cart object from json, but only in one controller method and that is:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public List<User> getUsers() {

    return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

User

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Name cannot be empty")
    private String name;
    @OneToOne
    private Cart cart;
}
```

Cart

```
@Entity
public class Cart {
    @Id
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    @OneToMany
    private List<CartItem> cartItems = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private User user;
}
```

I have done it with simple solution so i loop trough all users, and set their cart to null,and then anotated user entity with `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`
But i dont think this is propper solution, so im searching for some better solution..
How am i able to do this?

Thanks...

Comment: Please add your `Cart` model to clarify.

Comment: @xeofus's answer would be advisable in this situation. That way you have a model crafted specifically to respond to the request in the controller. Playing with serialization and entity management can create some unwanted side-effects. Such as nulling out columns or deleting references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create DTO (data transfer object) class like this:

```
@Data
public class UsersDto {
 private Integer id;
 private String name;

 public UsersDto(User user) {
  this.id = user.id;
  this.name= user.name;
 }
}
```

and than create `List<UsersDto>`

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public List<UsersDto> getUsers() {
    List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
    return users
     .stream()
     .map(o -> new UsersDto(o))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Data Projection](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections).

In your use case, you can use an interface projection:

```
public interface CartlessUser {
  Integer getId();
  String getName();
}
```

And In your repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
  List<CartlessUser> findAllBy();
}
```

The interface projection will help generate the sql query for only selecting the id, name fields. This will save you from fetching the `Cart` data when you're just going to throw it away anyways.